# Clients not authenticating with Domain Controller via WiFi (Server 2016, UniFi)

Tags: group-policy, authentication, pfsense, failed

I run a bit of a complicated setup, let me give you a quick rundown:

Local pfSense Firewall -> IPSec Tunnel to AWS -> Server 2016 DC.

pfSense runs DNS in the local network, forwards domain queries to the DC via Domain Override.

If I am connected via ethernet, everything works fine. Soon as I use WiFi (UniFi), I can't run gpupdate or print. When running gpupdate I get the error that the computer name can not be resolved.

When I reboot the machine, I get a Netlogon ID 5719, the computer can't establish a safe connection with the DC.

Why does this happen, and why does it work via ethernet and not WiFi?

Comment: Is your wifi on a different subnet?  If so, do you use routing or NATting to go from the pfSense to the Server 2016?  Probably worth updating your question with the answers

Comment: Hey Phil, no, the WiFi is on the same subnet. No, no natting towards the Server 2016.

Comment: can you post the output from "ipconfig /all" and "nslookup <doman name>" for wired and wireless connections.  where domain name is e.g. example.com